# How can I get access to Delphi's TField.DisplayText from _Recordset ADO interface?

Tags: delphi, com, ado, recordset, tdataset

I have passed `TDataSet.Recordset: _Recordset` interface using COM method outside the application. But I see there a wild DB data. How can I get access to Delphi's `TField.DisplayText` from `_Recordset` ADO interface? (`TField.DisplayText` shows data after `OnGetText` conversion.)

Comment: ADO [`Recordset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx) object doesn't know anything about how you display your data, so either create a new `_RecordSet` instance and fill it with `DisplayText` values and pass that object, or pass the way you're converting your data to that application separately (which would actually need to pass the code of your `OnGetText` event method).

Comment: But how can I create and fill _RecordSet instance? :(

Comment: Yet one more thing we need to know. What are you going to do with that dataset in the other application ? Are you going to modify it so the changes will apply to the underlying data source, or can it figure just as an independent in-memory table ?

Comment: "But how can I create and fill _RecordSet instance?"  Have you looked at the RecordSet interface in AdoInt.Pas?

Comment: Just independent in-memory table.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605901/how-to-export-tadodataset-with-fields-texts-not-fields-values/13607532#13607532

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks TLama for the answer:

> ADO Recordset object doesn't know anything about how you display your
>   data, so either create a new _RecordSet instance and fill it with
>   DisplayText values and pass that object, or pass the way you're
>   converting your data to that application separately (which would
>   actually need to pass the code of your OnGetText event method).